# Azure KeyVault and Authentication on client side

Tags: azure, security, authentication, websecurity, azure-security

Good day,

I have a question about the following scenario:

A client opens a web application in the browser. In the web application, secrets are retrieved from an Azure Key Vault using Javascript. Then, with these secrets a connection to another Azure service is established to retreive data.

Question 1: Azure Key Vault only secures the transfer of the secrets. The client could see / reverse engineer the secrets in the web browser after retrieval and see them in plain?

=> Is this correct and is this still secure?

Question 2: With these secrets the client can authenticate to the other service.

=> Is it possible that the authentication / use of the secrets is only allowed by the web app? So even if the user knows the secrets, he should not be able to use them in another application.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Azure Key Vault only secures the transfer of the secrets.
> The client could see / reverse engineer the secrets in the web browser
> after retrieval and see them in plain?
>
> => Is this correct and is this still secure?

That is correct.
If you load the secrets to front-end, the user can take the plain text.

> Question 2: With these secrets the client can authenticate to the
> other service.
>
> => Is it possible that the authentication / use of the secrets is only allowed by the web app? So even if the user knows the secrets, he
> should not be able to use them in another application.

I would say that is impossible.
Your app is a front-end public client application and thus cannot authenticate itself, meaning only the user can be authenticated.

I recommend that you do not load secrets to front-end if there is any possibility of their abuse should a user get them.
Instead you will either need a back-end or a different approach where you instead authenticate as the user to the service you are trying to access.
But that depends on the service, so please let me know what service you are trying to connect to.

Comment: Hi thanks!

Would it be possible when the other (secure) service allows only requests from the domain / ip of  the web app - but the web app is public (with network configuration, cors or something)?

Comment: Its a public Web App which gets secrets from Azure Key Vault and then Authentications to Azure Cognitive Services (there is a js library where you authenticate with the secrets of the keyvault).

My first idea was to use a separate function app which handles the service call. The function app is then called by the web app. So the user may see the function key (and could use it everywhere), but not other credentials.

Comment: Ah, Cognitive Services. I was checking and it seems it won't support Azure AD authentication with a user. Most likely you will need to implement the service calls in a back-end. Yes, the Function key would be visible and from a security point of view it might as well not require that key. A more secure version would require the user to sign in to Azure AD and use an access token acquired for the user to call the back-end.